# How can I run "Can You RUN It" app?

Tags: wine, firefox, java

I have used Ubuntu for quite some time now, but I'm having issues with this program I want to use.

I recently build a new computer, and wanted to use Ubuntu (because it's great), the problem is, I want to know if my new PC can handle the games I'm going to play in the near future. The website I use is called [Can You RUN It](https://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri).

The ways to see if you can run it are 2 ways, using Java, or using the desktop app. I downloaded the desktop app and ran it with Wine. For some strange reason, it showed the PC components I used for my last build. It didn't show the new components. I then went and installed IcedTea Java plugin for my Mozilla Firefox, but no luck.

How do I use this program for Ubuntu?

Comment: Their website didn't even ask to activate the Java plugin, so I'm not sure what's going on there. The desktop app was able to grab everything except my graphics card. Is there a reason you need to use a program instead of just looking up the recommended system requirements?

Comment: well i mean, i do like using the program...

Comment: Do you use Wine for any other programs? If not, try running winetricks, select the default prefix, and delete all data and applications. That should clean out any old data and force the detection program to find your hardware.

Comment: Looking at that website, it just give you and easy way to see your hardware specs.  As you built the computer, you should know what it's hardware is.  when you enter a game name, and click the "can you run it" button, the bottom of the popup is an option to see the game requirements yourself.  You can them compare it to your hardware specs.   I'm not sure how that will help you however.  When I did a quick search for Alien:Isolation. which I have so I know is Linux ported, it does not mention Linux as an option so you will have no way of knowing if the game will actually work on linux.

Comment: Additionally to TrailRider's words I'd say that the site seems to be buggy. Besides the system requirements being incomplete, their Java applet also never works — instead it just goes out with «Timeout». And they have no the obvious button like «Contact us» or «Report a problem». No surprise, actually — they're saying that the site is beta. So, you can't rely on this site, at least not yet.

Answer (score 1):

Well Can You Run It is a system requirements checking tool for any game for Windows. Basically it downloads and run a desktop app on your computer which you have to run it on your computer. This app then detects your hardware configuration and matches against the selected game requirements.

Note: The desktop app does not require you to install Java but make sure you have the latest version of the supported browsers.

If your hardware configuration is equal or above the game requirements then the result displayed on your browser is OK which means you can run that game otherwise a negative result is displayed suggesting you the necessary changes to for your hardware upgrade. I have written a complete guide on using this tool which you can find [here](http://www.akshatblog.com/can-i-run-it-how-to-know-if-my-computer-can-run-this-game/).